# RecycleView cannot be null - when asynchornous task is loading on one frag while on another frag

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin-coroutines

I have three fragments on an activity. On one I am loading a default view which is to be populated by data from Google Calendar but asynchronously -syncwholeCalendar(). While the app has loaded the default view, the app crashes when, Calendar data is being loaded and the user is on another fragment in the activity - saying the recyclerview cannot be null. Same is the issue, when I logout without waiting for the sync to complete... The issue is getEvents(), when the recyclerview is called to inflate it on sync... no issue when I am active on the fragment...

Is there a step I am missing or approach that I am taking incorrect?

```
class Home : Fragment() {
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun start(context: Context) {
        val starter = Intent(context, Home::class.java)
        context.startActivity(starter)
    }

    private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001
    private val transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport()
    private val jsonFactory: JsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
}

var usersReference: DatabaseReference? = null
var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
private var fabExpanded = false

//Calendar
private lateinit var mService: Calendar
private lateinit var calendar: java.util.Calendar
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressDialog
private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
private var isSynced = false
private var isFirstTime = false
private lateinit var googleCredential: GoogleAccountCredential
private var googleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)



firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


progressBar = ProgressDialog(activity)
    progressBar.setCancelable(false)
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...")
    calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()
    isFirstTime = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(
        "first",
        true
    )

    usersReference =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
    usersReference!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            if (p0.exists()) {
                val user: Users? = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)

                if (context != null) {
                    view.calEvenName.text = user!!.getFirstName()
                    view.calMornName.text = user.getFirstName()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })

    return view
}

private fun showCalendar() {
    val today = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()
    val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
        requireActivity(), R.style.DateTimePickerTheme,
        { datePicker: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int ->
            calendar.set(year, month, day)
            getCredentials()
        },
        calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(
            java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
        )
    )

//        datePicker.datePicker.minDate = today.timeInMillis
        datePicker.show()
    }

//closes FAB submenus
private fun closeSubMenusFab() {
    layoutFabNote.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    layoutfabEvent?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    layoutfabMsg?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    fabbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    home_fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_fab_24)
    fabExpanded = false
}

//Opens FAB submenus
private fun openSubMenusFab() {
    layoutfabEvent?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    layoutfabMsg?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    layoutFabNote?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    fabbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0F7FA"))

    //Change settings icon to 'X' icon
    home_fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_close_24)
    fabExpanded = true
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    //Only main FAB is visible in the beginning
    closeSubMenusFab()

    //Agenda Calendar Controls/Links
    homeCalendarDate.setOnClickListener { showCalendar() }

    rightCalArrow.setOnClickListener {
        calendar.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        getCredentials()
    }

    leftCalArrow.setOnClickListener {
        calendar.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)
        getCredentials()
    }

    //ResetDate Button
    resetIcon.setOnClickListener {
        //   Toast.makeText(activity,"Reset Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()
        getCredentials()
    }

    //FAB Buttons
    home_fab.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (fabExpanded) {
            closeSubMenusFab()
        } else {
            openSubMenusFab()
        }
    })

    fabMsg.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, MyContacts::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    fabEvent.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, AddEvent::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    fabNote.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, EditNote::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    //No Event cal display
    homecreateEvent.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, AddEvent::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    homesendMessage.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, MyContacts::class.java)
        activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

}

private fun getCredentials() {
    val date = SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.time)
    homeCalendarDate.text = date
//        progressBar.show()
        googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity)
        googleCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            activity,
            listOf(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)
        )
            .setBackOff(ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(googleSignInAccount?.account?.name)

    googleCredential.selectedAccountName = googleSignInAccount?.account?.name
    mService = Calendar.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, googleCredential
    )
        .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .build()

    if (!isSynced) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCredentials: syncing data")
        if (!isFirstTime) {
            getEvents()
        }
        syncWholeCalendar()
    } else {
        getEvents()
    }
}

private fun getEvents() {
    val noEvents = view?.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.no_events)
    val homeAgenda = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.homeAgenda)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        Log.d(
            TAG,
            "Time current: ${calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}, ${calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)}, ${
                calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)
            }"
        )
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)

        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity())
        val events = db.getEvents(calendar.timeInMillis)
        val listOfEvents = ArrayList<MyEvent>()
        for (event in events) {
            if (event.isPrimary) {
                listOfEvents.add(event)
            } else {
                listOfEvents.add(0, event)
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getEvents: ${events.size}")

        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            try {
                **val recyclerView: RecyclerView? = homeAgenda
                recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                recyclerView.adapter = EventsAdapter(**
                    requireContext(), listOfEvents, calendar.timeInMillis
                )
                if (listOfEvents.size != 0) {
                    noEvents!!.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    noEvents!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            } catch (e: UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                requireActivity().runOnUiThread { progressBar.dismiss() }
                startActivityForResult(e.intent, RC_SIGN_IN)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                requireActivity().runOnUiThread { progressBar.dismiss() }
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun syncWholeCalendar() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val calendars = mService.CalendarList().list().execute()
            val calendarsList = calendars.items
            for (cal in calendarsList) {
                val events = mService.events().list(cal.id)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute()

                // .setTimeMin(dateFrom)
                val eventsList = events.items
                for (event in eventsList) {
                    event.isLocked = !cal.isPrimary
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                        .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                        .collection("events")
                        .document(event.id).set(event)
                    var startTimeInMilli: Long = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
                    if (event.start.dateTime != null) {
                        startTimeInMilli = event.start.dateTime.value
                    } else if (event.start.date != null) {
                        startTimeInMilli = getAbsoluteDate(event.start.date.value)
                    }

                    var endTimeInMilli = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis

                    if (event.end.dateTime != null) {
                        endTimeInMilli = event.end.dateTime.value
                    } else if (event.end.date != null) {
                        endTimeInMilli = getAbsoluteDate(event.start.date.value)
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "syncWholeCalendar:${event.summary}, ${event.start.date} ${event.end.date}"
                        )
                    }
                    val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity())
                    val startTime = getAbsoluteDate(startTimeInMilli)
                    val endTime = getAbsoluteDate(endTimeInMilli)
                    db.insert(
                        MyEvent(
                            event.id,
                            event.summary,
                            event.description,
                            null,
                            null,
                            startTimeInMilli,
                            endTimeInMilli,
                            cal.isPrimary,
                            true,
                            startTime,
                            endTime,
                            event.location,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                    )
                    Log.d(
                        TAG,
                        "syncWholeCalendar: ${event.start.dateTime}, ${event.start.date}"
                    )
                }
            }
            isSynced = true
            requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("PRE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putBoolean("first", false).apply()
            getEvents()

            Log.d(TAG, "syncWholeCalendar: Data Synced Successfully")
        } catch (e: UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread { progressBar.dismiss() }
            startActivityForResult(e.intent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread { progressBar.dismiss() }
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    closeSubMenusFab()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    getCredentials()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `GlobalScope`. When you navigate away from a fragment/activity, its views get destroyed but `GlobalScope` bounds the task to the application lifecycle, therefore, it's not destroyed and referencing any views later will cause the app to fail with a `NullPointerException`.

So instead tie up the background activities to the fragment lifecycle by using `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` or `lifecycle.coroutineScope`. check out the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) for more info.

Comment: thanks rcs! this makes so much sense, have a additional question... in lifecycle my sync will get cancelled on moving to a diff frag/activity... so the Google Calendar data will not be imported... this would not be a great User experience considering the user has given permission already... how do I run the sync without the view being active?

Comment: try saving the data locally using room database, let the recyclerview depend on the local data to display the content and use activitylifecycle or scope of viewmodel scoped to the activity to run the background task as the `global scope`  is discouraged to go with.